# Perl alternative for screen/tmux for the UNIX world?

Tags: linux, aix, nohup

What happens when a screen/tmux-like solution is needed (to leave a process running for a long time, but not with `nohup` because interaction could be needed) - but screen/tmux is not available on the given machine, and installing screen/compiling it isn't a solution?

**Q: Are there any "short" perl scripts that can be generally (or not generally) used to achieve this goal (on Linux/AIX/etc.)?**

only this is needed:

1. start the perl script
2. start the given thing that takes long time
3. de-attach from the terminal, ex.: because working notebook needs to be shut
   down
4. **re-attach to the console** to see/control the started long running
   process, just like in screen

Does anybody has a perl script like this?

Comment: It may help if you comment on the answers you've received to explain why they're not satisfactory to you.

Answer (score 11):

`perl` may not be the most appropriate unless the `IO::Pty` module is installed.

First, maybe you don't need anything complicated if the given-thing-that-takes-long-time (gtttlt) can work OK with pipes.

```
mkfifo input
nohup gtttlt <> input > output 2>&1 &
```

to start the `gtttlt` (input from a named pipe, output to a regular file). Then you *attach* to it with:

```
tail -f output & cat > input
```

If pipes won't do and you need a terminal, then you would want to use something that can start a pseudo-terminal like `expect`, `zsh`'s `zpty`, `perl`'s `IO::Pty` or `sshd`:

```
mkfifo input
nohup ssh -tt localhost gtttlt <> input > output 2>&1
```

And to *attach*:

```
stty raw -echo; tail -f output & cat > input
```

Note that it's not like implementing `screen` or `tmux`. `screen` and `tmux` implement a terminal emulator. When you reattach, you see the content of the screen of that terminal emulator. Here when you reattach, you only see the last 10 lines of output (though you can adjust by passing a `-n 123` option to `tail`). And we're just passing along all the data to/from the host terminal.

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly what you asked for but I use `at` to do this. I often launch commands on remote servers from my laptop and then want to shutdown the laptop without losing the command's output. `at` allows me to launch jobs at a given time and I just redirect the job's output and error streams to files.

For example, if I want to run `my_script.pl` I will create a little file called `foo.txt` with the following contents:

```
my_script.pl > out 2>er
```

and then run it with

```
$ at now < foo.txt
```

I can then log off the server, take my laptop home and check the output by `ssh`ing to the server and running

```
$ tail -f er
```

or

```
$ tail -f out
```

You can also give `at` jobs from its shell (hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to exit):

```
$ at now
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> my_script.pl > out 2>er
at> <EOT>
job 10 at Thu Sep  5 00:39:00 2013
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the "at" suggestion above, I like this one better:

1. Start your perl script as usual "perl script.pl"
2. Do the user interaction stuff and get into the part that takes long
3. press ctrl+z to put it in the background and type "bg". The process runs now in tbe background
4. run "jobs" to see what number your process got. It is most probably 1.
5. run "disown %1" to deatch the progam to your current terminal.
6. you are now safe to close the terminal (type "exit" or just press the close button)

As an addition, you can redirect output to a file or named pipe. Unfortunately I don't think there is a way to attach the process again to your terminal.